# How can I fix my website's minimization issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble figuring out how to minimize my website with HTML and CSS. When I minimize the website the images are being hidden/not loading properly.
I tried going online but there are no clear answers on to how to solve this specific issue. If anyone could give me some insight or help me with this issue, it would be very much appreciated. Down below is my HTML and CSS code.

PS: I am still very NEW with HTML and CSS. I am learning how to build my own website for a personal project and would appreciate any tips and help unrelated to the question as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<title>Recreation of Angel's Store </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  

</head>

<!--This is the product header-->
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="wrapper"> 
            <nav class="header-nav" role="navigation" aria-label="Main">
                <ul>
                    <li class="choice">
                        <a href="/">PRODUCTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/">CART</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="branding">
                <a href="/" title="Home">
                    <div class="store-header">hanahaki02</div>

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class ="header-nav mobile-nav" aria-label="Mobile Main" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="choice">
                    <a href="/">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/cart">
                        Cart (<span class="cart-num-items">0</span>)
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>
    </header>
<!--This is the script for the cart that allows it to add an item-->
    <script>
        var cartItemCount = 0;
        document.querySelector('.cart-num-items').textContent = cartItemCount;
    </script>




   


    <hr class="custom-line2">

    <div class="list-title">
        Products
    </div>

<!--These are the image containers-->

    <div class="keychain-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain.html" class="href">
            <img id="keychain1" src="Images/8.webp" height="340" width="340" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a> 
       
    </div>

    <div class="animal-keychain-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain2.html" class="href">
            <img id="keychain2" src="Images/7.webp" height="340" width="340" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class ="stickers-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/stickers.html" class="href">
            <img id="stickers" src="Images/9.webp" height="340" width="340" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class ="photocard1-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard1.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard1" src="Images/10.webp" height="340" width="340" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">       
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class ="photocard2-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard2.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard2" src="Images/11.webp" height="340" width="340" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu"> 
        </a>
    </div>
    
</body>



</html>
```

```
type* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    
}

header {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 0 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-nav {
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    margin-top: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.header-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

.header-nav ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
    padding: 8px;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.branding {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 76px auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.branding > a {
    display: inline-block;
}

a[href] {
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    transition: color 0.1s linear;
    color: #111111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}


.header-nav.mobile-nav {
    display: none;
}



.store-header {
    color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
    font-family:"Varela Round", sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 42px;
    
}

.list-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.keychain-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
   
    
}

#keychain1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:400px;
    top: 50px;
    display: block;
    
    
}

.animal-keychain-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#keychain2 { 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    
    
}

.stickers-container {
    position: relative;
}

#stickers {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1125px;
    top: -343px;
   
    
}

.photocard1-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#Photocard1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:400px;
    top: 50px;
    display: block;

}

.photocard2-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#Photocard2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    
}




nav {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FBEFEF;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    
    
}

body {
    background: #FBEFEF;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    

    
} 

.parent-line {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}

.custom-line {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    border-top: 0.5px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width:15%;
    top: -60px;
   
}

.custom-line2 {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    border-top: 0.5px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width:60%;
   
}

.list-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
} here
```

Comment: What do you mean by minimize? And why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: This is my first time using HTML and CSS so there are certain commands that I am not aware of yet. I should probably mention that in my post next time. If you can give me some tips,, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using the viewpoint command. What I mean by minimize was every time I would minimize my website, the website would become cluttered and images would be missing. By using the <meta name = "viewpoint"  command I was able to solve this issue. @TimR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to individually position each image container by adding margin's and left and right offsets. A better approach that would dynamically scale down the images is to put them in containers that have a width of 33.33% (1/3 of the parent container) and make images have a width of 100%. then you can create a new `<div>` that wraps all the images. here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <!-- your code -->

    <hr class="custom-line2">
    <div class="list-title">Products</div>
    <div class="item-list">
      <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain.html" class="href">
            <img id="keychain1" src="Images/8.webp" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a>  
      </div>
      <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain2.html" class="href">
          <img id="keychain2" src="Images/7.webp" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/stickers.html" class="href">
            <img id="stickers" src="Images/9.webp" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard1.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard1" src="Images/10.webp" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu">       
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard2.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard2" src="Images/11.webp" alt="Chifuyu Ate" title="Chifuyu"> 
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and then add the following CSS styles:

```
.item-list{       /*parent container styles*/
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;          /* allows flex properties */
  flex-direction: row;     /* keeps elements in a row */
  flex-wrap: wrap;        /* wraps elements when they reach the edge of the screen */
}

.img-container {        /*img container styles*/
  max-width: 33.33%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {            /* img styles */
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as someone that is still trying to learn HTML and CSS, this is extremely helpful !  @P4dL4d

Comment: If u were trying to move the images to be closer to one another, how would u do so? Would u edit the CSS within the container itself using left and right offsets or is there a more efficient way to do so?